# Inline style in react does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using redux and react in my project and I set a color of an element in a reducer so whenever reducer is changed then the color of element will be changed. I checked my action and reducer and it works fine . But the rendering part is not does not add any style. My assumption is I am making a mistake in adding my style. Here is my code:

```
    render() {
    var style = {
        backgroundColor:this.props.channelTransitionReducer.backColor
    };
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12 header HeaderDummy" style={style}>
            <div className="row full-height">
            <div className="col-xs-1 adjust-col-1-desktop-left-right-margin"></div>
          .
          .
          .
    );
}
 }
```

As you see I use style variable then I add it to my element HeaderDummy. What is wrong with my code? any idea?

Comment: There's too little information to clearly identify what the issue is. And when you say it doesn't work, do you mean that in DevTools you can see the style not on the element? Also, have you tried to put a console.log to see this.props.channelTransitionReducer.backColor has the correct value, and is not undefined?

Comment: @AbhishekJain Yeah in dev tools there is no style with background color but yes  this.props.channelTransitionReducer.backColor has the right color in it

Comment: The code looks ok, unless I am missing something obvious. Would you be able to reproduce it in a codepen (or similar)?

Comment: if there is no error then backColor is probably not defined... try setting a default value `backColor || "blue"`. If the new color is blue then this is it.

Comment: @adz5A Right you answer helped me to find the issue. In the reducer I could see colors are coming but in render I was not accessing the object properly. If you post it I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is no error then backColor is probably not defined... try setting a default value backColor || "blue". If the new color is blue then this is it.